# Transfer file using SFTP from Windows to Linux

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssh, sftp, putty

I need to transfer files from my windows based server to my Linux server using SFTP protocol. They are in the same LAN network.

I have enabled SFTP on my Linux server.
Using:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
sudo apt-get install ssh
```

I made a group (I call it sftponly) and a user (abc) for my SFTP server.
I am using PuTTY as my SSH client in Windows environment.
In my Windows, I have a text file located in `c:/myfile/myfile.txt` and I want to upload this file using SFTP into my Linux server

My batch file code looks like:

```
start putty.exe -ssh 192.168.0.117:4747 -l admin-pw Password -m C:\\test\ssh.txt
```

The contents of my `ssh.txt` is:

```
sftp abc@192.168.0.117
put c:/myfile/myfile.txt
```

I am sure the `put` syntax is wrong because we are in Windows environment. What is the missing code in my `ssh.txt` file so I can upload the `myfile.txt` into SFTP?

The abc user has all the privileges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The remote `sftp` process cannot access the local files on your Windows machine.

*(Even if it could, your script file is still wrong, as the the `put` will be executed [and not understood] by a shell, not by the `sftp`.)*

---

You have to use a local SFTP client to upload the files to the remove SFTP server.

The PuTTY comes with the [`psftp.exe` SFTP client](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html) that mimics the OpenSSH `sftp` client.

```
psftp.exe abc@192.168.0.117 -b C:\test\ssh.txt
```

Where the `ssh.txt` contains the `put` command:

```
put c:\myfile\myfile.txt
```

Comment: You saved my life, its work perfect. Thank you.